# MVC 5 Windows Authentication Requiring Credentials In Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I created a new MVC 5 project and selected windows authentication. When I debug the website in Internet Explorer 11, everything works great. However, when I debug the website in Google Chrome it is requires credentials or throws Error code: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED. This is right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This is on setting of your browser. This can work with chrome browser (see Integrated Authentication):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/http-authentication